# Typesetting Tolkein's elvish (and a script request)

Tags: fonts

I'm looking to typeset some Elvish characters, but from an English to Tengwar transcription.

I've found this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nbeaver/tengwarscript-install-guide#tengwar-quenya-tengwar-sindarin-tengwar-noldor) which has made installing all the necessary bits and pieces nice and easy, after chasing a few threads/links on here.

However, I need a script to convert between English and the actual Tengwar characters to by typeset. The repo alludes to one, but the link is defunct for me. This is probably a long shot, but does anyone have a suitable substitute that works with the `tengwarscript` package, or a way of getting hold of a copy of that script?

Comment: the tengwarscript package is on ctan.  try the ctan search: https://ctan.org/search

Comment: the tex package isn't the issue, it was the transcriber script I was after. I'm going to close this myself anyway as I managed to find an archived version no sooner than posting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to track down a version of the script on the WayBackMachine, and I've reuploaded it to Github for future reference:

https://github.com/jrjhealey/PerlTengwarTranscriber